# homework questions deleted by poster - authentication by teacher

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, homework

Suppose a question is given by a teacher to a student, who obtains an answer here, copies it and then deletes the question. Is there an easy way for the teacher to prove that the student has not actually done the work?

I have no evidence of this happening, but I would be surprised if it has never happened.

Comment: I have caught it happening as the teacher, but I stopped it before an answer was provided. But even though the username was a first name, I couldn't link the account to any specific real person

Comment: Forget about this website, Peter; is there *ever* "an easy way" for a teacher to prove that a student has not done the work the student hands in? And if there's no easy way in real life, why would there be an easy way here?

Comment: The internet gives tons of possibilities to "cheat" , of course this cannot be prevented. Even at this site where the policy is not to answer "homework questions" (or at least looking like homework) , this happens often because of various reasons. This is the price of the internet, no novelty has only advantages. Proving it will be difficult since the users , although registered , are usually not known , and even if this is the case, the teacher will have a difficult job to find the deleted post.